# Comment $links order in drupal

Tags: php, drupal

In the comment.tpl, $links is printed to show the reply and edit link. In my theme, edit comes before reply. How do you change the order of the printed links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`hook_link_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_link_alter/6) - it allows you to manipulate the links before they get rendered, e.g. remove some or change the order.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a comment preprocess function in template.php in your theme. That should give you access to the $links variable and allow you to re-order the elements.

Comment: Good idea. I tried using unset ($links['comment_reply']); in the preprocess function, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This function will reverse the order of comment links. Put it in your template.php (also after adding the function empty your site caches and visit /admin/build/themes once to make sure this function is picked up in the theme registry):

```
function phptemplate_links($links, $attributes = array('class' => 'links')) {
  if (isset($links['comment_edit'])) {
    krsort($links); // or ksort if you want to order your links the other way
  }
  return theme_links($links, $attributes);
}
```